# Display List Column on Web Page Part

Tags: list

SharePoint 2007 - I have a custom list with multiple columns to display project properties. This list will only ever contain a single entry(for a single project). The list will be populated using the standard item edit features. I would like to display one of the columns (only one) from this list (project overview) on a web page. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new View to the list and add only the required column.

Now edit the page and add new webpart -> Choose the List and Select the View.